# Handle App going background in middle of UILongPressgestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I am using UILongPressgestureRecognizer to add a subview to a view on `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and removing this view when gesture ends.

My problem is, when app goes to background before ending this gesture (by clicking home button or power button to lock screen ) the subview which I added will be still there when user resumes the app (back to foreground).

Please suggest me some way to handle this. 
I know about `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` delegate in `AppDelegate` but I don't know how to use this delegate to solve my issue because this functionality is there in multiple `UIViewController`.

Comment: Have you checked recognizer for UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification) to get notified when the app is about to enter background. Each `UIViewController` can subscribe to the notification on its own.

Then you can cancel the gesture by doing:

```
recognizer.enabled = NO
recognizer.enabled = YES
```

**Edit**

[As user1963877 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236072/handle-app-going-background-in-middle-of-uilongpressgesturerecognizer/26236178#comment41151249_26236072) you should also check whether an app going to the background already causes the  gesture recognizer to enter cancel state anyway. You'll just have to check for that in your gesture handler then and remove your subview.

Comment: If app is going background will gesture handler be called with cancelled state??

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a reference to the `UIViewController` presenting the subview. When your app goes to `applicationDidEnterBackground`, you call a method on your referenced UIViewController to remove the subview.
Something like :

```
[AppDelegate.referencedViewController removeSubviewFromScreen];
```